# Reading contacts from android & converting to JSON

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

How to get all information like primary & secondary mobile numbers, Email, Fax, image and making json array from those information...

Currently I can able to get primaryContact and and one name. I can able to show them in CUSTOM listview just like whats app.

Comment: Why would you convert that to JSON? You can read contacts (name, number etc. ) from phone and present them in listview

Comment: Hello Yupi, Thanks for the quick reply... I need to send them(contacts) to server

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code to create a json object: Currently I'm fetching all the phone numbers, Email, Organization Details, Title for a all the contacts.

**Note: You will require read contact permission**

**Code in Kotlin:**

```
private fun getContacts(): JsonArray {

    val resolver: ContentResolver = contentResolver
    val cursor = resolver.query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
        null
    )
    val mainJsonArray: JsonArray = JsonArray()
    if (cursor!!.count > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val personJsonObj: JsonObject = JsonObject()
            val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
            val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
            //val phoneNumber = (cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER) )).toInt()
            personJsonObj.addProperty("NAME", name.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("'", "\\'").replace("\"", "\\\""))

            val orgCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", arrayOf(id), null
            )

            val phoneJsonArray = JsonArray()
            val emailJsonArray = JsonArray()

            if (orgCursor!!.count > 0) {
                while (orgCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if (orgCursor!!.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE)).equals(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                        )
                    ) {
                        val companyName = orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))
                        val designation = orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA4))
                        personJsonObj.addProperty(
                            "ORGANIZATION",
                            companyName.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("'", "\\'").replace("\"", "\\\"")
                        )
                        personJsonObj.addProperty(
                            "DESIGNATION",
                            designation.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("'", "\\'").replace("\"", "\\\"")
                        )

                    } else if (orgCursor!!.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE)).equals(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                        )
                    ) {
                        val phoneNum = orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))
                        phoneJsonArray.add(phoneNum.replace(" ", "").replace("-", ""))
                    } else if (orgCursor!!.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE)).equals(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                        )
                    ) {
                        val emailAddr = orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))
                        emailJsonArray.add(emailAddr.replace(" ", ""))
                    }
                }
            }
            orgCursor.close()
            personJsonObj.add("EMAIL_LIST", emailJsonArray)
            personJsonObj.add("PHONE_NUMBERS", phoneJsonArray)
            mainJsonArray.add(personJsonObj)
        }

    }
    cursor.close()
    return mainJsonArray
}
```

**The Resulting JsonArray:**

```
    [{
        "NAME": "Test User Test User Last Name",
        "ORGANIZATION": "Some Company",
        "DESIGNATION": "Associate",
        "EMAIL_LIST": ["testuser@organiztion.com", "testuser1@org.com"],
        "PHONE_NUMBERS": ["123456789", "9808776"]
    }, {
        "NAME": "User One",
        "ORGANIZATION": "Test Company",
        "DESIGNATION": "Owner",
        "EMAIL_LIST": ["abc1@test.com", "abc2@test.com", "abc3@test.com", "abc4@test.com"],
        "PHONE_NUMBERS": ["7777", "8888", "9999"]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read contacts with something like this, I used it in my app and it's working:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

`if (cursor != null) {
      if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {`

```
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

`String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          }
       }
   }`

And for posting data on server here is some example: http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

Hope some of this will help you.